# NodeJS JWT token verification

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth0

I'm trying to verify a signed token and extract information from it using NodeJS.

I have a token named userToken in the browser right now, it has been saved after I logged in (I use auth0 to login by the way).

I tried to verify my token here manually : http://jwt.io , it works and gives me payload data without a problem. However, I can't do the same thing with NodeJS. How can I do it?

I read the docs but I couldn't get it.
https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt

Here's my server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.load();

var authenticate = jwt({
    secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
});


// view engine setup
var path = require('path');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.configure(function () {

    // Request body parsing middleware should be above methodOverride
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors());

    app.use(app.router);
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/test', function(req,res) {
    // how do I check it?
});


var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

http.createServer(app).listen(port, function (err) {
    console.log('listening in http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

Comment: Node is telling you that `jwt` doesn't have a `verify` function, and indeed it looks like it doesn't.

Comment: It looks like there's a connection between express-jwt and jsonwebtokens, I'm trying to figure that out. https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken

Comment: Yes, `jsonwebtoken` creates (or signs) tokens for `express-jwt` to process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sample should help you, it's not tested, but sure it's right way, look at source of `express-jwt`, it does [literally same behind the scenes](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt/blob/master/lib/index.js#L108)

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    var jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken'); //install this, move to declarations
    var loginToken = req.headers.authentication || req.body.userToken || req.headers.Bearer; //or your own, it's just headers that pass from browser to client
    jsonwebtoken.verify(loginToken, new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'), function(err, decoded) {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(401).send({message: 'invalid_token'});
        }
        //be aware of encoded data structure, simply console.log(decoded); to see what it contains
        res.send(decoded); //`decoded.foo` has your value
    });
});
```

The thing is that you must yourself encode your data, and then decode, so be aware that auth0 returns valid data structure for you (as i'm not sure otherwise)

Comment: Thank you, it's almost done. If I pass the token as string, it works. But if I try req,headers.userToken or req.body.userToken, it returns invalid token since probably it can't find token in there. What could be the reason causing that? How can I find which req object to call (headers, body, etc) to get the userToken?

Comment: My token is in the localstorage, should I install a module to get it or is there a built in way to fetch it?

Comment: @salep Browser must send token with headers(or body), to do this, get token from localstorage, and patch all your outgoing http requests with that token (add to headers), that's it

Comment: I successfully implemented it, it works for jQuery Ajax post requests, but still have problems with get requests. Thank you for your help, I appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You dont't need to implement nothing. Since you are using this `express-jwt`, just pass the `userProperty` tag to `jwt`:

```
var authenticate = jwt({
    secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    userProperty: 'payload'
});
```

So, you can get all of your jwt payload data using `req.payload` in your controllers. You can check it with `console.log(req.payload)`.

You can see how it works here: https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt/blob/master/lib/index.js#L121

I hope it helps, and sorry about my English.

Comment: What is userProperty?

Comment: This should be the best answer.